# AWS RDS move production database into staging. Most efficient way?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to know the most efficient way to move our production database into our staging env?

Using AWS RDS. I have tried searching and have had no luck find a way to use an existing RDS snapshot to replace our staging database. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fire up a new RDS from a recent snapshot. Point your code at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a mysql Dump from the RDS machine and push it to the Staging machine

```
mysqldump -P port_no -h RDS_IP -u mysql_user -ppassword database_name
```

Comment: this will work, but is not the most efficient method - as it will just dump the database, the database will then needed to be loaded into the remote. (mysql -u mysql_user -ppassword database_name < dumpfile name)